# How do I create a token that automatically gets urls convert to trackable links?

Tags: civimail, tokens

This is kind of the opposite of [Integrating CiviMail tracked links with Google Analytics](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/integrating-civimail-tracked-links-with-google-analytics)

In other words, I'm generating html for civimail using tokens, and the html includes links, but those links are not getting converted into trackable links. I think there's probably some code I could include in my hook_civicrm_tokenValues function to convert my embedded urls into trackable links, just like the Civi core code does. Or maybe I have to tell Civi that it's okay to do this using some settings?

Comment: On a related question - is it possible to create custom 'domain' tokens, i.e. ones that are only calculated once for the mailing? Judging from a scan in the code for Hook::tokenValues, the answer seems to be no.

Comment: And further afield - maybe this is the wrong strategy for including auto-generated content? An alternative would be a wyswyig button that pulled in auto-generated content, giving the author full control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BAO responsible for trackable URLs is `CRM_Mailing_BAO_TrackableURL` link [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/6c6872a8ee5acec3dba231fe2231c610241302eb/CRM/Mailing/BAO/TrackableURL.php#L56).

Because the `MailingJob` is available in `hook_civicrm_tokenValues` you could do something like this:

```
// job details to get mailing_id 
$job_id = civicrm_api3('MailingJob', 'getsingle', array(
        'id' => $job,
));
// get event_queue_id
$queue_id = civicrm_api3('MailingEventQueue', 'getsingle', array(
        'job_id' => $job,
        'contact_id' => $cid,
));

$url = 'https://example.com';
$trackableUrl = CRM_Mailing_BAO_TrackableURL::getTrackerURL($url, $job_id['mailing_id'], $queue_id['id']);
```

RE: "wyswyig button that pulled in auto-generated content" 
[HTML Buttons](http://ckeditor.com/addon/htmlbuttons) plugin for CKEditor does what you describe, I have a couple of dropdowns with buttons that insert complex HTML snippets, is what I use for composing newsletters.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, just what I was looking for, works.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Whoops - this worked on a test, but not for a real mailing. The missing bit was to get the queue_id with the extra parameter of contact_id => cid. In other words, the event queue id is not unique per job id, it has be to pulled separately for each contact. But then it worked!